# DNS Issues after Updating to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, wifi, vpn, dns, ping

I've updated to Mountain Lion, and I'm having some DNS problems. I always PPTP/L2TP VPN connections on my macbook. Recently after a while of working with Mountain Lion, VPN stops sending and receiving data and I have to disconnect/connect again to make it work again. I'm not having the same problem with iPad, iPhone and PC.

and without the VPN, when I try pinging 4.2.2.4 , 8.8.8.8 and other DNSs and all I get is timeouts! But the ping works fine on my other devices. I also tried setting the DNS to Google and OpenDNS DNSs (8.8.4.4, 4.2.2.4, 8.8.8.8, ...) but it still didn't help. I also tried emptying DNS cache and other solutions. but nothing.

I'm guessing that these two problems are tied together.
Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to OS X 10.8.1 fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

change the primary DNS to your local gateway address, like 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.10...
I have the same problem in PC, try it, It may be useful ;)

Comment: In Mac OS it is set to local gateway by default if you don't provide any other DNS. So that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

in windows too but set it manually, and use the "4.2.2.4" in secondary DNS server... if u have this Problem without VPN, use one of these DNSs : 217.218.155.155 or use the "namebench" software to find best local DNS server for u...
;)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/namebench/